# Fragment data not getting on tabunselected

Tags: android

I have three fragments with the one activity associated .I want data of all three fragments in one string on the click of a button which is on the actionbar.I am getting data when i unselect the tab.But when I am on the last tab I am unable to get the data.Any type of help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an interface with a static variable and all the fragments extend of this interface.
The static variable can be kinda ArrayList, HashMap or something else. So using it you will be able to access all the data you want.

Comment: Thanks Lennon, Can you please elaborate the solution with example.It will be helpful for me.I am not getting how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The interface that I said:

```
public abstract class FragInterface extends Fragment {

    public ArrayList<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();

}
```

The fragment e.g:

```
public class FragExample extends FragInterface {

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxxxx, container, false);

   }


}
```

In the activity:

```
private ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener mSimpleOnPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        super.onPageSelected(position);

        // you can get something

        ((FragInterface)((SimpleTabPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter()).getItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem())).objectList.get(indexOfData);

        // or you can add something

        ((FragInterface)((SimpleTabPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter()).getItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem())).objectList.add(objectYouWant);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}

};
```

Comment: Thanks  but I have implemented another solution.This will not work for me because its using viewpager and I am not using ViewPager in my app.

Comment: Ok, no problem. However, I used a viewpager just for example and you can use that solution with whatever component you'd like.